# Challenge does not handle challenge with adapter based authentication

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have been trying to develop adapter-based authentication for an application, and I'm not quite sure why the challenge handler does not get triggered here.

**Client-side main.js:**

```js
var AuthenticationHandler = WL.Client.createChallengeHandler("EventAuthRealm");

AuthenticationHandler.isCustomResponse = function(response) {
  if (!response || !response.responseJSON || response.responseText === null) {
    return false;
  }
  if (typeof(response.responseJSON.authStatus) !== 'undefined') {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};

AuthenticationHandler.handleChallenge = function(response) {
  var authRequired = response.responseJSON.authRequired;

  if (authRequired == false) {

    WL.logger.debug("done");
    busyIndicator.hide();
    AuthenticationHandler.submitSuccess();
    toEventList(); //function to navigate to next page


  } else if (authRequired == true) {

    WL.logger.debug("false");
    busyIndicator.hide();
    AuthenticationHandler.submitFailure();
    WL.Logger.debug(response.responseJSON.errorMessage);
  }
};
```

**Login function:**

```js
function login() {

  var reg = $("#attendeeId").val();
  var userpw = $("#attendeePw").val();

  busyIndicator.show();
  var invocationData = {
    adapter: "eventdbAdapter",
    procedure: "submitAuthentication",
    parameters: [reg, userpw]
  };

  AuthenticationHandler.submitAdapterAuthentication(invocationData, {});

};
```

**HTML code of the login page:**

```html
<div data-role="page" id="eventloginpage">
  <div data-role="header" align="center" data-theme="b">Event app</div>

  <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px" id="wat">
    <input type="text" name="attId" id="attendeeId" placeholder="Attendee ID">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="attendeePw" placeholder="Attendee Password">

    <!-- Buttons here -->
    <a href="#" data-role="button" id="loginButton" data-theme="b" onclick="login();">Login</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" id="button" onclick="logout();">Logout for now</a>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer" align="center">Text</div>
</div>
```

If this might be related, I built the multipage component of the application following the tutorial that uses pagecontainer change.

**Example:**

```js
function toEventList() {
  $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', 'eventpage.html');
}
```

Whenever I execute the login function, everything works as intended up until submitAdapterAuthentication is called.

Google Dev console returns a timeout on the request. When executing the app on an Android device, Logcat displays a status code of 201. I can only assume that the object is created successfully with the information collected from the fields, however, the handler does not submit the credentials at all.

Any kind of advice would be greatly appreciated. I apologise in advance if my post seems silly as I am not quite experienced with MobileFirst and Web technologies in general.

Comment: status code of 201 means .The entity format is specified by the media type given in the Content-Type header field. The origin server MUST create the resource before returning the 201 status code.on the other hand. 201 status code indicates that a request was successful and as a result, a resource has been created (for example a new page).

Comment: so please share your adapter code .or flowing proper documentation https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/all-tutorials/

Comment: Thank you for your reply Hasan. I added the code for the adapter's js and xml files in the following link: https://jsfiddle.net/srvc0pk7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why it did not work properly before. On the adapter side I was not using strict equality operators against the test login values within submitAuthentication() as demonstrated in the example. I assumed the other types of equality operators would work, however, that does not seem to be the case. This is not written in any of the documentation as far as I could tell.

The 401 error I mentioned before seems to be a check performed by the MobileFirst server against one of the built in components according to the documentation.

I also made sure to clean the server and re-deploy the application on it.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know what version of MFP you are working with, so that you can look at the appropriate documentation.

Please make sure that the follwing is implemented in the wlCommonInit(). As you can see from the documetation here, [Documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_client_connect.html), it is need to contact the worklight server

WL.Client.connect(
        {
            onSuccess: onConnectSuccess,
                onFailure: onConnectFailure
            });

Comment: Thank you for pointing  that out and sorry for not including it in the beginning. I am using MFP 7.1.0. I was missing connect() from wlCOmmonInit() indeed. No changes with the browser console. On my Android device I get FWLSE0335E: Authorization failed Client ID not found on sever.

Comment: please clear the cookie cache for the webbrowser, close it and try it again

Comment: Still the same. I noticed that as a potential solution multiple times when searching but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: can post the main.js file so that I can have a look?

Comment: Yes please. I tried a few new things with it in the meantime and some of the methods are slightly different from my initial post. JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/xvo0pvve/

Comment: Can you make this global? var AuthenticationHandler , i.e, outside the wlCommonInit() and then see if this changes the console output?